# How would I generate a random sequence of numbers without going accidently going over the same numbers?

Tags: python, random

This is probably a duplicate of something, but oh well.
I'm trying to create a random number generator that goes over all 7 digit numbers (0000001 - 9999999) but I'm having issues thinking how I'd code such a mechanism; would anyone know any libraries or functions that may help here?

Edit: Big thanks to Kelly Bundy and Alexpdev for helping me understand how I can code this script

Comment: `but I'm having issues...`. Can you give an example of the issues you are having? When you says `goes over all` does that mean you want to output 10 million values? Or are you only trying to generate a single (or a few) value(s) from that range? As far as libraries...well there is [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Comment: What are you going to do with that?

Comment: Are you looking for a manual solution so you can understand the code for such a problem, or are you looking for an out-of-the-box solution you can use in your other code?

Comment: Keep track of the numbers you've already generated.  If you generate a duplicate, just try again.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers linked in the original post comment section, you can also use `numpy` to generate an array of x length and randomise the order:

```
import numpy as np

x = 10000000
a = np.arange(x)  
np.random.shuffle(a)
print(a)
```

[This is the example straight from numpy's website](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html#:%7E:text=Modify%20a%20sequence%20in%2Dplace,their%20contents%20remains%20the%20same.)

`np.arange(x)` creates an array from 0 to x-1, stepped at 1. Numpy can then shuffle your array inplace.

Beyond 9 digits, this answer becomes unfeasible due to memory limitations, in which case you'd simply be better off using a generator or RNG function.

If you want to format your number as a string and fill it with padding zeros, eg 0000020 instead of 20, you can do:

```
str(a[idx]).zfill(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `random` module that comes with python you can use the `randint` function to get a random integer in the range of it's arguments.

Then cast the result to a `str` and pad it with "0"s for the desired output.

```
import random

def get_random_sequence():
    num = random.randint(0,9999999)
    return str(num).rjust(7,"0")
```